# Not able to save data in cosmos db through spring boot micro service

Tags: spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

i'm trying to save entity in cosmos db through spring boot micro service. I'm not getting any error, only 1 warning '**[osEventLoop-6-1] c.a.d.c.i.d.rntbd.RntbdRequestManager    : ChannelHandlerContext(RntbdRequestManager#0, [id: 0x999bfbac, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:56979 ! R:cdb-ms-prod-*****-****.documents.azure.com/********]) channelUnregistered exceptionally**' 
but data is not getting saved in cosmos db. i'm using reactivecosmosrepository.

here is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <azure.version>2.2.0</azure.version>
    </properties>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

my entity

```
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "dashboardsnapshot")

public class DashboardSnapshot {

    private String id;
    private String clientId;
    private String snapshotJSON;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }
    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }
    public String getSnapshotJSON() { 
        return snapshotJSON; 
    } 
    public void setSnapshotJSON(String snapshotJSON) { 
        this.snapshotJSON = snapshotJSON; 
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DashboardSnapshot [id=" + id + ", clientId=" + clientId + ", snapshotJSON=" + snapshotJSON + "]";
    }

}
```

my repository

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.ka.concept.dashboardconfig.entity.DashboardSnapshot;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.repository.ReactiveCosmosRepository;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Repository
public interface SnapshotDao extends ReactiveCosmosRepository<DashboardSnapshot, String>{

    Flux<DashboardSnapshot> findbyClientId(String ClientId);

}
```

my service

```
@Service
public class SnapshotServiceImpl implements SnapshotService{

    @Autowired
    public SnapshotDao snapshotdao;

    @Override
    public boolean saveSnapshotConfig(DashboardSnapshot snapshotJSON) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        snapshotdao.save(snapshotJSON);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB developer's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/how-to-guides-spring-data-cosmosdb). There's a ton of new content there that may help you find the answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

@AksYou should call subscribe(). The publisher does not do anything till some one subscribes.

snapshotdao.save(snapshotJSON).subscribe();